# getting HTML source or rich text from the X clipboard

Tags: linux, xorg, clipboard

How can rich text or HTML source code be obtained from the X clipboard?  For example, if you copy some text from a web browser and paste it into kompozer, it pastes as HTML, with links etc. preserved.  However, `xclip -o` for the same selection just outputs plain text.  I'd like to pull the HTML out and into a text editor.

Comment: It does appear to obtain the HTML source itself: things like the class properties of <div> elements are preserved.

Comment: improve the title of your question to match what you really want: the source code of the website / rich text...

Comment: @akira: Thanks for your suggestion.  It would have been more polite to phrase it as such.

Comment: not polite, just more to the point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261379/getting-html-source-or-rich-text-from-the-x-clipboard/3263632#3263632) to the stackoverflow.com fork of this question, I built a [ghetto command-line client](http://github.com/intuited/clipcli) to pull this info.

### Usage

```
clipcli [-h] [-f FILE] [-d] [-l] [TARGET]

positional arguments:
  TARGET                display the contents of this target

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d, --debug           enable debug tracing
  -f FILE, --file FILE  the file to which output will be directed
  -l, --list            list available targets
```

### Example:

```
$ clipcli text/html
some text with <em>emphasis</em>
```

The way this works, even the availability of different targets, seems to depend a lot on the application which is providing the clipboard data.  There's a bit more info at [the stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261379/getting-html-source-or-rich-text-from-the-x-clipboard).

Answer (score 2):

You can also:

- Copy from the formatted source.
- Run this command to extract from the clipboard, convert to HTML, and then (with a pipe `|`) put that HTML back in the clipboard, again using the same `xclip`:

```bsh
xclip -selection clipboard -o -t text/html | xclip -selection clipboard
```

- Next, when you paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, it will paste the HTML source.

---

Going further, you can make it a **shortcut**, so that you don't have to open the terminal and run the exact command each time. ✨

To do that:

- Open the settings for your OS (in my case it's Ubuntu)
- Find the section for the Keyboard
- Then find the section for shortcuts
- Create a new shortcut
- Set a **Name**, e.g.: `Copy as HTML`
- Then as the command for the shortcut, put:

```bsh
bash -c "xclip -selection clipboard -o -t text/html | xclip -selection clipboard"
```

**Note**: notice that it's the same command as above, but put inside of an inline Bash script. This is necessary to be able to use the `|` (pipe) to send the output from one command as input to the next.

- Set the shortcut to whatever combination you want, preferably not overwriting another shortcut you use. In my case, I set it to: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

---

- After this, you can copy some formatted text as normally with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- And then, before pasting it, convert it to HTML with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- Next, when you paste it with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, it will paste the contents as HTML. ✨

**Note**: cross-posted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540366/219530 , but it's also relevant here.

[image: Shortcut edition window]

Answer (score 0):

Does `xclip -o -selection secondary` or `xclip -o -selection clipboard` work for you?

These could be abbreviated to

```
xclip -o -se s
```

and

```
xclip -o -se c
```

Comment: No, that still gives a textual rendering of the page rather than the HTML source.